# Way to combine integer array to a single integer variable?

Tags: java, arrays

After finding the individual digits of a number by remainder procedure, the numbers are saved in an array. 
What I want now is to take the individual elements of this array and make a single integer value of it.

eg.

```
int a = 4400
```

digits saved in array by using recursion (4400/10) :
let array be arr[]

```
arr[0]=0;
arr[1]=0;
arr[2]=4;
arr[3]=4;
```

final value:

```
int b= 4400 (by combining elements of array)
```

So I want to know if there is any way to combine the array elements to a single integer value ?

Comment: Multiplication and addition.

Comment: There is a way. It is similar to the way you decomposed it. Please make a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just multiply and add the digits:

```
int result = 1000 * arr[3] + 100 * arr[2] + 10 * arr[1] + arr[0];
```

Or, if you need it to work for any length of array (up to the number of digits in `Integer.MAX_VALUE`):

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  result = 10*result + arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Using `i--` should be avoided in loops when possible, because it goes even further against what you could consider human mathematical and logical reasoning. Just leaving this comment here for new users searching same answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a stringbuilder.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(arr[3]);
builder.append(arr[2]);
builder.append(arr[1]);
builder.append(arr[0]);
System.out.println("Combined value is: " + Integer.parseInt(builder.toString());
```

Comment: As you can see in the question final value should be an `int` again.

Comment: The result is not an int, and the digits are reversed.

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: Its useful thank you JBiss

Answer (score 0):

How about using simple loop and multiplication (assuming you know basic math)

```
int b = 0;
int z = 10;
for (int i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
   b = (int) (b + (arr[i - 1] * Math.pow((double) z, i - 1)));
}
```