# Integer iteration Help java

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation

I am currently having an issue regarding combining a integer array into an integer.

I looked into a couple of other ways to do them at [Way to combine integer array to a single integer variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607753/way-to-combine-integer-array-to-a-single-integer-variable), but I still do not understand why I am running into errors.

My goal is to turn:

```
[6, 2, 3, 3, 8, 7, 7, 7, 0, 1, 6]
```

into

```
62338777016
```

It currently works when given smaller integer arrays such as:

```
[1, 3, 4, 4]
-> 1344
```

It starts breaking down once the number of elements reaches 10.
Does anybody have a possible solution?

Comment: If your number is larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE, you'll have to use either Long or BigInteger.

Comment: MAX_INT = 2147483647

Comment: I can work with longs, but if I use bigInteger how would I go about it?

Comment: You are breaching the max integer limit. Hence, you are seeing your solution breaking. As Eran suggests, use a better datatype, which supports wider range.

Comment: can someone give me an example regarding how to use BigIntegers in this case? I've read a little about BigIntegers and it seems that they constrict too many functions

Comment: Also, I'm a newbie :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overflowing the integer's maximum size of 2147483647. One way to address this is to use a [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead of an `int`:

```
BigInteger bigInt = BigInteger.ZERO;
for (int i : ints) {
    bigInt = bigInt.multiply(BigInteger.TEN).add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a reverse iteration?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj no. OP wants the first element of the array to represent the left-most digit on the result.

Comment: @Mureinik does this program directly make 62338777016 out of the int array? I am confused as I have never used Big Integer

Comment: @chimmichanngas pretty much. You can think of a `BigInteger` as a really really large `int` that just uses methods like `multiply` and `add` instead of operators like `*` and `+`.

Comment: This is not good for performance because of multiple `BigInteger` instances to be created.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the Error message to be sure but my first guess will be that you reach the size limit of int (2,147,483,647).

Comment: [6, 2, 3, 3, 8, 7, 7, 7, 0, 1, 6]
2147483647
[2, 3, 3, 8, 7, 7, 7, 0, 1, 6, 5]
2147483647
[3, 3, 8, 7, 7, 7, 0, 1, 6, 5, 3]
2147483647
[3, 8, 7, 7, 7, 0, 1, 6, 5, 3, 8]
2147483647
[8, 7, 7, 7, 0, 1, 6, 5, 3, 8, 8]
2147483647
[7, 7, 7, 0, 1, 6, 5, 3, 8, 8, 7]
2147483647
[7, 7, 0, 1, 6, 5, 3, 8, 8, 7, 3]
2147483647
[7, 0, 1, 6, 5, 3, 8, 8, 7, 3, 4]
2147483647

Comment: The array is the integer array and the number next to it is the combined element number

Comment: You can use long or BigInteger but more important is that you check the size of the array and validate that you are not overflowing

Answer (score 0):

Well one possible way to solve this, I am assuming all integers are positive.

You can concatenate all integer array values into a String and form a single string.

So, `[6, 2, 3, 3, 8, 7, 7, 7, 0, 1, 6]` becomes `62338777016` (String).

BigInteger has a constructor (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String))

That you can leverage, to get a BigInteger representation of the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform it like this:

```
Integer[] arr = {6, 2, 3, 3, 8, 7, 7, 7, 0, 1, 6};
Long val = Long.valueOf(Arrays.stream(arr).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining("")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to use a integer for more than 10 digits which exceeds maximum value of 2,147,483,647, so you could use the below code which make minor changes like using a double.

```
  Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { 6, 2, 3, 3, 8, 7, 7, 7, 0, 1, 6 };
    Double myData = 0d;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        double productfactor = (Math.pow(10, (arr.length-1-i)));
        myData = myData+arr[i]*productfactor;
    }
    String formatted = new BigDecimal(Double.valueOf(myData)).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long convert(int[] arr) {
    long res = 0;

    for (int digit : arr) {
        // negative value is marker of long overflow
        if (digit < 0 || res * 10 + digit < 0)
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        res = res * 10 + digit;
    }

    return res;
}
```

This is not an universal method, because of `Long.MAX_VALUE`. Otherwize, you have to use `BigInteger` isntead of long.

```
public static BigInteger convert(int[] arr) {
    // reserve required space for internal array
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(arr.length);

    for (int digit : arr)
        buf.append(digit);

    // create it only once
    return new BigInteger(buf.toString());
}
```